# Jump to another label from within a label

Tags: installation, nsis

**In NSIS, how do I jump to a label from within another label?**

Note: I am not sure if what I am talking about is actually called a label so correct me if I am wrong.

In the following code I want to jump to the label 'InstallFiles', see the line '# SEE HERE':

```
# the following code is from within a macro
# Check the directory exists
IfFileExists $installDirectory InstallFiles CreateDirThenInstall

CreateDirThenInstall:   # this is a label...I think? :P
  file $installDirectory
  # SEE HERE: HOW DO I call the label 'InstallFiles'?

InstallFiles:
  DetailPrint "SetOverwrite on."
  SetOverwrite try
  SetOutPath "${dir}"
  file "Attributes_to_trees_panel.4do"
  file "ATTRIBUTES_TO_TREES_PANEL.hlp"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have nothing to do** for going to the `InstallFiles` label from the line below `CreateDirThenInstall` : just let the execution reach the following line.

You might have misunderstood that labels do not actually declare sub programs, they only put "signs" that can be reached from any flow control instruction (in the *current* Function or Section) like `StrCmp`, `IntCmp` and `Goto`s. If there are statements above a label and there is no jump or `Return` just before it, the execution continues to the next statement after the label.