# Set global variable from within macro

Tags: installation, nsis

In NSIS Script Language I get an error when I go access a global variable from within a macro.

Is my variable installDirectory truely global? How can I set the variable installDirectory from within a macro or function(if its possible within a function)?

```
var installDirectory

!macro IdentifyDir
   IfFileExists C:\test\9.00\ Version9 AbortInstall

   Version9:
      $installDirectory "C:\test\9.00\"
   AbortInstall:
      Abort
!macroend
```

Also can a Macro &/or function return a value in NSIS(or shd I just use push/pop)?

```
!macro IdentifyDir
   IfFileExists C:\test\9.00\ Version9 AbortInstall

   Version9:
      return "C:\test\9.00\"
   AbortInstall:
      Abort
!macroend

var installDir !insertmacro IdentifyDir # is that valid?
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [assembly]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues :

- to assign a variable, you miss one assignment instruction; for a string variable you can use `StrCpy` : `StrCpy $installDirectory "C:\test\9.00\"`
- as stated in [your another question about labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10426008/317266), labels are not subs but only some defined points that can be reached by flow control, thus when jumping to the `Version9` label, without another jump the execution will run to the `Abort` statement that follows the the `AbortInstall` label. You should *either* put another label like `end_of_macro:` before the the `!macroEnd` statement and add a `goto` before the `AbortInstall` label (beware that that the macro is expanded *where* you put the `!insertMacro` so you must choose a unique label name, it is not like for sections or functions) *or* (more elegant) invert the two labels : in the case of the abort the execution will stop there and in the second case it will continue outside of the macro

```
!macro IdentifyDir 
    IfFileExists C:\temp\9.00 Version9 AbortInstall
AbortInstall:
    Abort
Version9:
    StrCpy $installDirectory "C:\test\9.00\"
!macroend
```

For your question concerning the return value, you can use the default registers `$0` to `$9` and `$R0` to `$R9`